# Jest cannot resolve scoped path

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using the scoped path for types as `@some-types`. It's getting compiled fine, but when I'm testing components with imported modules, Jest can't find this module - ModuleA is undefined. I assume that something is wrong with jest config.
Type module example:

```
export module ModuleA {
...
}
```

Types modules exported with index.d.ts.

```
export { ModuleA } from "./ModuleA";
```

Usage of the imported module:

```
import { ModuleA, ... } from "@some-types";
```

tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
      ...
      "@some-types": [
        "src/types/index.d.ts"
      ],
    }
```

jest.config.ts

```
export default {
      globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
         babelConfig: true,
         useESM: true,
         tsconfig: "tsconfig.test.json"
      }
   },
      collectCoverage: true,
      coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
      moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'd.ts'],
      moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
      resetMocks: false,
      setupFiles: ['jest-canvas-mock'],
      moduleNameMapper: {
        ...
        '^@some-types$': '<rootDir>/src/types/index.d.ts',
      },
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
      },
      testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
      testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '/lib/',
        '/scripts/'
      ],
      verbose: true,
    };
```

P.S. The other scoped paths defined in moduleNameMapper as `^@hooks.(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/hooks/$1'` getting resolved fine.

Comment: I found that it's not directly related to the scoped paths but to enums that were defined in the types.